# Does recycling the IIS7 application pool kill any currently executing requests?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, windows-server-2008, application-pool, recycle

Does recycling the IIS7 application pool kill any currently executing requests? Or does it wait for all requests to complete (like a drain-stop)?

I don't want the recycling rules to cause intermittent errors from my WCF sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

> By default, the WWW service
>   establishes an overlapped recycle, in
>   which the worker process that is to be
>   terminated is kept running until after
>   a new worker process is started.

This is from the [Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3ee19598-ec90-4570-a4a5-d93a24400b99.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS6 and I am sure it applies for IIS7.

If your web service requests are long-running, you might consider increasing the shutdown timeout.

Comment: The answer seems to be yes and no. No, the processes can be staggered if there is more than one process running; or yes if a long-running request exceeds the shutdown timeout. I'll see what shutdown timeout values I'm using and make sure that they exceed my longest running service call. Thanks.

Comment: "Greg. Sorry I was confused and thought I was editing my post :-) I realised it later and removed my editing. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Recycling an application pool causes the WWW service to shut down all running worker processes that are serving the application pool, and then start new worker processes.

This is from the [Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f11b8294-cc42-4e9c-8482-6257bf3b80f2.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS6 and I am sure it applies for IIS7

Comment: If you read until the DisallowOverlappingRotation parameter part, you'll that the answer depends on how this parameter is set.