# Stop App Pool while a WCF Service Processing - Kill Current Process

Tags: wcf, iis

While deploying changes to WCF Service, the app-pool is stopped. Hosted on IIS8. Messages are queued by MSMQ, however we are concerned that in-process services will fail when the app-pool is stopped.  Does anyone know if the app pool is stop is smart enough to allow current processes to finish prior to shutting down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does recycling the IIS7 application pool kill any currently executing requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630420/does-recycling-the-iis7-application-pool-kill-any-currently-executing-requests)

Comment: I agree that it may be a duplicate.  However, that question refers to a recycle rather than a stop.  Wasn't sure if there is a difference.